# get a particular column element of the next table row from database

Tags: php, sql-server, while-loop, comparison

I have a query which selects `userid,messageid,statusid` from `tableA` like following.

```
$qry = mssql_query('select userid,messageid,statusid from tableA');
if(mssql_num_rows($qry))
{
   $data = mssql_fetch_array($qry)
   {
     //if(current_status_id column value != next_status_id column value)
     $status = $data['statusid'];
   }
}
```

I need to compare the value of current `statusid` column with the immediate next row  `statusid` column like this `if(current_status_id column value != next_status_id column value)`.Is this possible.Pls help me

Comment: @GordonLinoff So its not possible to get the next row element ....Also I am using sql server databse and using mssql() ,not mysql()

Answer (score 1):

```
$qry = mssql_query('select userid,messageid,statusid from tableA order by statusid');
while (($row=mssql_fetch_array($qry) !== FALSE) {
    if (isset($previous) && $previous['statusid'] !== $row['statusid']) {
        // do what you gotta do here
    }
    $previous = $row;
}
```

I added `order by statusid` to your SQL so that you do get an order set of data.  And rather than trying to "look ahead" to the next row, the code above "looks back" to the previous row ... which is effectively the same.  You've got the data of the two rows in `$previous` and `$row` so you should be able to do what you wanna do with `$previous`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an array and assigned the results into it.Then I used while loop and checked if the current element is not equal to next element.

```
$i=1;
while (($row = mssql_fetch_array($qry, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false)
{
     $data_array[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
} 
mssql_data_seek( $qry, 0 );
while($msgDetailChilds = mssql_fetch_array($qry)){ 
   if($data_array[$i]['groupid']!=$data_array[$i-1]['groupid'])
   {
      //do stuff
   }
```

}

Comment: This way you are iterating twice over the same result set, which is not effective.